# Complicated container switch - 4-page home page

Tags: html, css

I tried, and tried, looked for possible answers here, W3C, ect, but am still stuck.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Are you trying to create an image carousel? - 
for example this : https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp

Comment: Not really. That is what makes it so tricky. It's actually like a "4-page" on One.
Pages are fixed to the browser size, that’s it (each page has a different background).
To see all content on each page, there will be a DIV which hold that content and this DIV scrolls automatically ( or should be fast forward scrollable (on mobile devices …just like you do it with any page).

It will be a different experience than usual, where you’d have simply one long page and people can roll through (nobody does anyway :) )  

Thanks
Can't attach screenshots, sorry

Comment: Ops, can't include (not in comment)  the script I have so far.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far & create a minimal example of your effort. Also take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for you interest but there's no need. Overall attitude on here is very low so I decided to delete all my questions. No point hanging around a group of arrogant. Apology to the few who aren't, like yourself, but i go rather to a place where questions are honoured, not "silently" down-voted. Again, thanks anyway